# Getting files based on their first letter into directories

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement, while-loop

Create a shell script (sorter.sh) that loops through all items in a directory given by the user using the "read" builtin. This input needs to be able to accept directories using a tilde. The script must validate the input and use a loop to only allow the script to proceed after the validation is complete. It must validate that the directory given is a directory.

The script, while iterating over the items in the directory, should test the items to see if they are directories or files. If they are directories then they need to be renamed to add the current date to the end of the directory name. If they are files they need to be copied into another directory given by the user and force testing purposes must be the path (~/Desktop/sorted). Note that you can not hard code this directory path into the program, you must use the variable taken in from the user. Inside this other directory your script must also create directories named with the starting of "cis90-" and the ending of a through z. So the first three directories would be "cis90-a", "cis90-b", "cis90-c". The files that are getting copied need to be copied into the folders alphabetically. All files beginning with the letter "a" go into the "cis90-a" folder, files beginning with the letter "b" go into the "cis90-b" folder, files beginning with the letter "c" go into the "cis90-c" directory. In order to save you some extra work after you get to "c" all additional files should go into the "cis90-d" directory.

I've got as far as where i need to go over the items for directories and files.  Not sure how to get the files into the cis90 folders.  Here's what i have so far.

Edit: Im now looking into using a case command to separate the directories and files.  then copy the files into their respective folder.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +%m%d%Y)

read -p "Enter directory for items to be sorted: " dir

eval dir=$dir

while [ -z "$dir" ]; do
        read -p "Empty entry.  Enter directory: " dir

done

while [ ! -d "$dir" ]; do

read -p "Invalid entry. Enter directory: " dir
done

read -p "Enter directory for cis90 directories: " cis

    eval cis=$cis 
        for j in $cis; do 
                mkdir $cis/cis90-{a..z}
        done

for i in $dir/*; do

        if [ -d $i ]; then 
                echo "$i is a directory."
        fi
done
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `eval dir=$dir` & `eval cis=$cis` ?

Comment: still it is not required...
It will esp fail, if the dir value is something like `/ ls` (basically, if it contains a command & a special character.)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a file, you need to extract the base filename and then get the first letter of the filename. Once you know what the first letter is, you can copy it into the appropriate directory. This can be done using ["Parameter Expansion"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) (type `man bash` and search for Parameter Expansion).

For example, if the file is `foo/bar.txt`, the basename is `bar.txt` and the first letter is `b`.

```
$ i="foo/bar.txt"
$ echo "${i##*/}"     # get the basename
bar.txt
$ i="bar.txt"
$ echo "${i:0:1}"     # get the first letter
b
```

Here is your updated script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +%m%d%Y)

read -p "Enter directory for items to be sorted: " dir

while [ -z "$dir" ]; do
    read -p "Empty entry.  Enter directory: " dir
done

while [ ! -d "$dir" ]; do
    read -p "Invalid entry. Enter directory: " dir
done

read -p "Enter directory for cis90 directories: " cis

mkdir $cis/cis90-{a..z}

for i in $dir/*; do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then 
        echo "$i is a directory. Moving $i to ${i}_$DATE"
        mv "$i" "${i}_$DATE"
    elif [ -f "$i" ]; then     
        filename="${i##*/}"
        firstletter="${filename:0:1}"
        echo "Copying $i to $cis/cis90-$firstletter"
        cp "$i" "$cis/cis90-$firstletter"
    fi
done
```

I've also made some changes like removing the `eval`s because I don't believe it is required.